# Get-ChildItem pipeline into ForEach-Object Get-ItemProperty - $_ path concatenates Current Working Dir with HKLM registry path?

Tags: windows, powershell

I've checked a few answers here and found that this seems to be a common problem but none of the suggestions were working for me.

When I do

```
Get-ChildItem "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\"
```

It returns what is expected, a list of all the registry keys ("thingys") in that registry location ("registry folder thingy"), namely the network adapters in my machine (including hidden ones).

Now I want to not just dump everything into the output, just the `DriverDesc` value for each of those keys, i.e. "Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265" and some weird "Microsoft ISATAP Adapter" names as well.

Pipelining this command into a ForEach-Object Get-ItemProperty party seems like the ideal solution, however when I try that I get a weird error:

```
Get-ChildItem "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\" | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.Name}
```

Error:

```
Get-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Folder\Powershell\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0000' because it does not exist. 
At line:1 char:155
```

It seems that the pipeline doohickey is concatenating my current working directory with the HKLM registry path and trying to access that registry key, which of course doesn't exist.

To be sure the piplining isn't being weird, I tried to just write the names out:

```
Get-ChildItem "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\" | ForEach-Object {Write-Host $_.Name}
```

And the results were what I expected:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0000
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0001
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0002
```

But the problem seems to be that the path provider gets dropped in the pipeline party and Get-ItemProperty doesn't handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I figured out that to get what I wanted I needed to append the path provider `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::` again to the pipeline party output and then work with the results.

```
Get-ChildItem "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\" | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::$_"}
```

Gives the correct output, but I want to display only the DriverDesc, which I can do as follows

```
Get-ChildItem "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\" | ForEach-Object {$(Get-ItemProperty "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::$_" -Name DriverDesc).DriverDesc}
```

Output, as I wanted:

```
Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM
Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
```

I also found that I could use $_.pspath

```
Get-ChildItem "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\" | ForEach-Object {$(Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath -Name DriverDesc).DriverDesc}
```